# EXCEL Get a subset of rows from a column of date without VBA

Tags: excel

I have multiple sheets of data with the date in column A and a value in column B.
I want to plot the same shifting date range from all sheets (e.g. the past seven days) - so that I can compare the data in one chart. However, the data's "spacing" isn't always the same, so I can't just plot the same number of rows for each sheet.

I've figured out ways to find the rows I want. This gives the first entry for seven days ago:

```
=LOOKUP(TODAY()-8,sheet1!A:A,ROW(sheet1!A:A))+1
```

Then I use the COUNT function to get the last value. Now I want to plot the data in this range.

I've tried named ranges but I can't seem to get it to work. Anybody have an idea?

Best regards,
Andrew

Comment: so you have manage to pull the first and last row NUMBERS?

Comment: Hi Forw.Ed! Yes, I have the starting and ending row numbers for the range I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=INDEX(INDEX(A:A,first row number formula):INDEX(A:A,last row number formula),0)
```

you now have a range of matching dates for column A:A,  repeat for column B:B

You could also use the OFFSET function

```
=OFFSET($A$1,first row number formula -1,0,count of number of cells to return,1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Both formula you gave result in a `#VALUE!`error... even when I 'hardcode' the start and stop values (or the number of cells, in the second suggestion), by just putting in the numbers I've determined...

Comment: hrmm I can see part of the problem.  They return arrays.  If you put the formula in and empty column, select the top most cell you want to have the formula in and drag down for 7 rows.  Enter the formula in the top cell with the other cells still selected.  Instead of pressing enter, press CTRL+SHFT+ENTER.  you will see {} added around the formula in the formula bar if done right.  you cant add them manually.  You may need to reformat cells to display date correctly.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick... highlight the desired range with the first cell being the origin of highlighting and fill in the formula - then press cmd+shift+enter.  So relieved! I spend hours fiddling with this... thanks again!

Comment: I have been fiddling with it as well, you should have been able to make the offset function a named formula, and then used the name formula as the series for you graph.  but I just could not get that to work.

Comment: I am glad the "IDEA" got you moving forward at least.